# inserting scores data into a quiz_user join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a quiz app and I have to keep track of users along with the quizzes that they appeared for any their score for that quiz so I thought that creating a join table (has_and_belongs_to_many relationship)quizzes_user which will have the quiz_id, user_id and the score might be the best way to go about it but I am not able to insert the scores into the table..

any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: In the Join table you can't store any score so you need to make a separate tables scores which a model Score Belong to user and belong to quiz and it will store all the score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `has_and_belongs_to_many` use `has_many through:`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :quizzes, through: :results
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quiz
end

class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :users, through: :results
end
```

Since a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association does not have a model for the join entities there is no straight forward way to query it directly or add additional columns to the join table.

Here you would create the "result/score" by something like:

```
@quiz.results.create(user: current_user, score: 99)
```

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is only actually a good idea if you know that you'll never need those features and the memory savings from not instanciating join models. This is only the case if the join entity is not an actual "thing" in itself.